# StrToDate cannot convert value obtained from DateToStr

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have an old application. It has a date in localized format stored in its data. This string was only used for display, so it was acceptable to have it in the localized form.
Now we need to reuse it as a TDateTime. It seemed to be simple: because we obtained the string from DateToStr, we will convert it back using StrToDate. So I wrote a small console program to verify it:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;
var
  S:String;
  D: TDateTime;
begin
  S := DateToStr(Now);
  Writeln(S);
  D := StrToDate(S); //! throws an EConvertError
  Readln;
end.
```

It throws an EConvertError:
Project Project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message ''28. 9. 2017' is not a valid date'.
This is incorrect, the in-exception mentioned date is valid! It was generated via DateToStr just a moment ago.
This completely doesn't make sense to me.
Could this be a bug in Windows 10?

Comment: How does it fail? Does it throw an error? Is the output unexpected?

Comment: That works. Rest assured, it does.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Do you really have spaces before the "9" and the "2017" in the error message and the writeln output? Hint: you can copy text from the console window through the system menu (edit - > mark and then edit -> copy).

Comment: I notice you have an upvote and a reopen vote, possibly someone was able to duplicate the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It works for me.

Comment: @Rudy - I was wrong, people who reopened the question are not Delphi related.

Comment: @Sertac: Unfortunately, I can't see who did. If they are not "Delphi related", I wonder what made them reopen it.

Comment: @Rudy the information is shown in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46472404/revisions) page. The question probably ended up in some sort of review queue maybe because of the downvotes or my delete vote and the edit to the question probably convinced the reviewers that it is reproducible.

Comment: @Sertac, I see that these people have indeed nothing to do with Delphi. Hmmm... I wonder what makes them think they know enough to reopen it. I usually skip such revisions (i.e. ones about which I have no knowledge at all).

Comment: The question contains a lot more information after the edit, so maybe these people thought it worthwhile for others to at least look at it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can duplicate your issue if I enter `dd. M.yyyy` for short date format in regional settings of the OS. Or `dd. M. yyyy` to have the exact error message you quoted in the question, note the spaces in the format strings.

The reason `StrToDate` fails is that the `ScanDate` function in "sysutils.pas" fails and returns False. The reason `ScanDate` fails is an incorrect date separator in the default format settings record.

RTL retrieves the date separator with the below code, in which `LOCALE_SDATE` is passed for `LocaleType` parameter and "/" is passed for the `Default` parameter.

```
...
var
  Buffer: array[0..1] of Char;
begin
  if GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LocaleType, Buffer, 2) > 0 then
    Result := Buffer[0] else
  Result := Default;
```

In the case of your date format the required buffer is 3 characters, since the RTL provides only 2 chars the API fails with `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` and the above function, not concerned with the fail reason, returns the default date separator of "/". So this is an error in the Delphi RTL.

If you have a valid use case for your odd format string, use the `StrToDate` overload that receives a format settings parameter. If not, just correct your date strings in regional settings.

Unfortunately you cannot apply a generic solution for the first alternative. That is you can retrieve the correct date separator with, e.g., like this:

```
function GetDateSeparator: string;
var
  NumChars: Integer;
begin
  NumChars := GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDATE, nil, 0);
  Win32Check(NumChars <> 0);
  SetLength(Result, NumChars);
  Win32Check(GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDATE, PChar(Result), NumChars) <> 0);
  SetLength(Result, Length(Result) - 1);
end;
```

But you cannot assign the returning `'. '` to the `DateSeparator` of a `TFormatSettings`, because it expects a Char. You have to pretend you know the separator is a `'.'` and use that, and that only works because the second char is a space which is stripped in `ScanDate`.

Comment: I wrote a function to avoid this odd RTL behaviour:

Comment: Wanted to paste my solution, but comments are probably not intended for this? This page is not screen reader friendly. The comment edit is a multiline, so I expected ability to write multi line text, but after pressing Enter the comment was saved. It is useless but I am unable to delete it, sorry.

Comment: @Lubos - You can also use `VarToDateTime` (variants), or `VarDateFromStr` (varutils) directly which calls the API to do the conversion.